# Search dialog box

Tags: search

Is this [search dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBce1.png) possible in SF (search trigger by letters, partial name)?

[image]

Or is there any way to get a scroll box with all the objects on the lookup field

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Technically speaking pretty much everything you can do in a web page is somewhat achievable in Salesforce, and this falls under this umbrella.

You could write your own search using the Lightning Design System guidelines, or you could implement a component built by the community, such as **[lwc-lookup](https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-lookup-lwc)**, for example.